# help with process_template_response django middleware

Tags: django, middleware

I'm trying to write a django middleware using process_template_response but I seems like it's not working, can anybody help me with this or maybe give an example on how to use the method.

below is my code:

```
class MiddleWare(object):
    def process_template_reponse(self, request, response):
        response.context_data = dict(title='title')
        response.template_name = 'pages/helloworld.html'
        return response
```

in settings.py

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'proj.app.middleware.MiddleWare', # here my middleware
)
```

in template

```
<!-- nothing is showing -->
{% block title %}{{ title }}{% endblock %}
```

by the way I'm using Django 1.3 rc 1

Thanks

Comment: When you say "nothing is showing", have you checked the raw response?

Comment: You have a typo its `process_template_response` not `process_template_reponse`

Answer (score 7):

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/middleware/#process-template-response

Are you using the new [`SimpleTemplateResponse`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/template-response/#django.template.response.SimpleTemplateResponse) response classes?

Your view must return `SimpleTemplateResponse` or subclass for the new `process_template_response` middleware hook to work.

Copied from the docs:

```
def my_view(request):
    # Create a response
    response = TemplateResponse(request, 'mytemplate.html', {})
    # Register the callback
    response.add_post_render_callback(my_render_callback)
    # Return the response
    return response
```

Comment: I've converted my view so that it will return a TemplateResponse instead of HttpResponse but still not getting the expected output. Do you think you can provide a complete example on how to do this? Thanks

Answer (score 7):

**TL;DR**: You must render your templates with `TemplateResponse`:

```py
from django.template.response import TemplateResponse

def myView(request):
    context = {'foo':'foo_value'}
    return TemplateResponse(request,'foo.html', context)
```

---

The problem arises when you render your templates with the good old `render` imported from `django.shorcuts`. As stated in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/middleware/#process-template-response) for `process_template_response()`, this hook gets called when the response is a `TemplateResponse` or equivalent. So what you should do is to use `TemplateResponse` to render your templates and your middleware will work.

You can also alias `TemplateResponse` as `render` so you don't have to change all your views. I personally don't recommend this.

```
from django.template.response import TemplateResponse as render
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is a working example of a simple middleware that uses the process_template_response method.

```
class ExampleMiddleware(object):
    def process_template_response(self, request, response):
        response.context_data['title'] = 'We changed the title'
        return response
```

This middleware changes the value of the title variable in the template context data. Install this middleware by adding it to MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES in your settings file. Then visit any page in the django admin app you should see the title of the page change to *We changed the title*.

Answer (score 2):

I've solved my problem creating a custom template tag. I'm just wondering on how to add a context variable using a process_template_reponse in a middleware.